# convert Ocaml/Haskell type definition to Haskell: * in definition

Tags: haskell, f#, ocaml

trying to convert type definition from Ocaml/F# to Haskell, getting an error:

```
error: parse error on input `*'
```

How could I correct the code?

current **Haskell** code:

```
data Func sa sb =
    Empty
    | Leaf Int * (sa * sb) List
    | Branch Int * Int * (Func sa sb) * (Func sa sb)
```

**Ocaml:**

```
type ('a,'b)func =
Empty
| Leaf of int * ('a*'b)list
| Branch of int * int * ('a,'b)func * ('a,'b)func;;
```

**F#**

```
type func<'a,'b> =
    | Empty
    | Leaf of int * ('a * 'b) list
    | Branch of int * int * func<'a,'b> * func<'a,'b>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data Func a b
    = Empty
    | Leaf Int [(a, b)]
    | Branch Int Int (Func a b) (Func a b)
```